# Automatic message when someone requests to join my group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I am a administrator of a group in Facebook and we have hundreds of requests to joing the group per month, and most of them don't follow the criteria to join.
I would like to know if it's possible when someone asks to join the group, to send a automatic message to that person (without accepting her/him automatically).

Answer (score 2):

The closest you have is the [Ask Pending Member Questions](https://www.facebook.com/help/200755420421098) feature in groups

It allows you to set questions that people who request to join need to answer:

> If you're an admin, you can require people who request to join your group to answer up to 3 questions. Questions are limited to 200 characters.

And so:

> When someone goes to your group and clicks **Join**, they'll see a form that includes the questions you've set. If someone's invited to join your group, they'll receive a notification to answer the questions. Clicking the notification will take them to the form.

The questions are not mandatory, but you can write in the questions dialog that anyone who doesn't answer the questions - his request is ignored.

> - Prospective members can respond to only one question or all questions, responding is not mandatory.
> - If a prospective member clicks **Cancel**, their request will still go through.

If users don't answer the question, they will get notifications reminding them to answer:

> If they did not answer the questions, members will receive 4 automatic notifications (after 3 hours and after 1, 2 and 3 days). Notifications will stop after 3 days.

## How to set those questions:

> **To ask questions:**
>
> 1. Click **More** below the cover photo and select **Manage Group**.
> 2. Click **Member Requests**.
> 3. Click **Ask Pending Member Questions**.
> 4. Add your questions and click Save.
>
> **To edit the existing questions:** (1-3. Same as previous)
>
> 4. Change your questions and click **Save**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option available as of now. You can [request to Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/127103474099499) for a new features.

To make your group more secure you can change the [privacy settings](https://www.facebook.com/help/220336891328465?helpref=faq_content).